# Can't connect to azure virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, azure

I've been running a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance on Azure for many months. When my application suddenly became unavailable, a bit of digging reveals the VM shows the attached error under "boot diagnostics". Without access to the host it's a bit difficult to troubleshoot. I don't have a support contract, and was directed here for help.

Comment: Which "attached error"?

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting unbootable Azure VMs is a royal pain, because Azure provides no console access; your best bet would be to download the VM's virtual disk, attach it to a Hyper-V host and work on that.

Alternatively, if you know what to fix and how to fix it (f.e. modifying a Registry entry, or copying a missing file), you can attacch the disk to another, working Azure VM; of course, this can also be done on a local system (all recent versions of Windows are able to mount VHD disks natively).

---

BTW, whoever "directed you here for help" was thoroughly wrong; ServerFault is not a support site, nor should it be treated as such.